# Asp.net core 2.2 intercept and change route data values - url localization

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

Would it be possibile in asp.net core 2.2 to intercept, for each request, the route data and (possibly) change the values, such as the target `controller` / `action` values?

My need is to use a localized url scheme, with two letter culture specification and localized controller / actions names, such as:

```
/en/contact-us
/it/contatti
/de/kontakte
```

i don't want to use attribute routing to decorate controllers and actions; instead, i want to capture the route data and basing on `culture` and `controller/action`, obtain the target controller and action, maybe with a dictionary association.
I've already done such thing in asp.net (not core) mvc.

Until now i'm able to capture routing with this code:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var routeData = context.GetRouteData();


            routeData.Values["controller"] = ....;
            routeData.Values["action"] = .....;

            await next();
        });
```

but route data is filled only for urls precisely mapped to an existing controller/action else is null; it seems this is due to the `AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute` method of asp.net core, which only maps existing controllers/actions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Your custom middleware won't work because there'll be no `RouteData` before it enters a `RouteMiddleware` (e.g.`UseMvc()`). One way to walk around it is to create a  Router to map a middleware and use mvc when matched.

Comment: @itminus, any working example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a walkaround that works for me:

```
// if the route matches this pattern, let's say:
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => {
    routeBuilder.MapRoute("route1",template: "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});

// else if the route matches `{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}`
app.UseRouter(routeBuilder =>{
    var template = "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}";
    routeBuilder.MapMiddlewareRoute(template, appBuilder =>{
        appBuilder.Use(async(context, next)=>{
            var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
            var controller = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;
            var action= routeData.Values["action"] as string;
            var culture= routeData.Values["culture"] as string;
            // get the real backing path according to current route data
            context.Request.Path = getNormalizedPath(routeData);  
            await next();
        });
        appBuilder.UseRequestLocalization();
        appBuilder.UseMvc(rb=>{
            rb.MapRoute(name:"cultureRoute",template:template);
        });
    });
    // if you have other MVC routes, add them below:
    // routeBuilder.MapRoute(name:"mvcRoutes",template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});

// else if doesn't match the above pattern, let's say:
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => {
    routeBuilder.MapRoute("route3",template: "/test/mvc/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

```
private string getNormalizedPath(RouteData routeData)
{
    var culture= routeData.Values["culture"] as string;
    var controller = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;
    var action= routeData.Values["action"] as string;

    controller = ... real controller according to current culture & controller string
    action = ... real action according to current culture & controller string
    return $"/{culture}/{controller}/{action}";
}
```

You need custom the `getNormalizedPath(routeData)` to get the real path that will be routed to the backing controller/action.

To set the Request Localization Feature automatically according to current route path at the same time, you'll need to insert a `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]{
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
        new CultureInfo("de"),
        new CultureInfo("it"),
    };
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

---

As found by [@ʞᴉɯ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182331/%ca%9e%e1%b4%89%c9%af) in the comments, the first `UseMvc()` doesn't work well for 2.2. We need change the MVC Compatibility to `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1`:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: Great! ___Thanks

Comment: Trying to use other MVC routes with routeBuilder.MapRoute, i get 'A default handler must be set on the IRouteBuilder.' error.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ Sorry, I made an bug. Please see my updated code. The updated code is just a demo that invokes mvc for different routes both before and after the culture routes. If you don't need `route1`  or `route3`, feel free to remove them.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ As a side note, as of `ASP.NET Core 3.0` (likely will be released in Sep this year), the new Endpoint Routing middleware will enable the feature to get routes values before the router get executed. Till then it might be rather easy to achieve your goal without so much hard work.

Comment: if i put on top the first rule
          app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => {
                routeBuilder.MapRoute("Blog",
                    template: "/Blog/{page:int=1}",
                    new {controller="Main", action="Blog"}
                    );
            });
 then  UseRouter directive is called but no longer works.. 404

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ I'm so sorry that I provided your an incorrect code snippet again. I test your code and find that it is caused by the endpoint routing behavior that is introduced in `ASP.NET Core 2.2`: If I keep the `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)`, I could reproduce the same issue as yours. But if I change it to `SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)`, the culture router middleware wroks fine for me.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ I've edited my answer. So sorry for the incorrect code.